# Get Json Value with extra quotes using php

Tags: php

Get all value from json using `json_decode`. Given name is `Juliet"es` this json. If using `json_decode` this array will be change null value. how do i get this json to array

```
$jsonobj = '{"Name":"Juliet"es","Maths":37,"English":43}';
```

if anyone having any idea please post answer.

Comment: Because that is invalid JSON

Comment: Literal quotes need to be escaped. `$jsonobj = '{"Name":"Juliet\"es","Maths":37,"English":43}';`

Comment: The extra `"` in `Juliet"es` is the root cause of the issue. If you want to use `"` inside a quoted string, you need to escape it: `Juliet\"es`

Comment: This is why you should always use `json_encode()` to create JSON, instead of trying to create it by hand.

Comment: Where did you get this “JSON” from? Did you create it manually? DO NOT ever do that. Create & fill the appropriate data structure in PHP, and then use `json_encode` to encode it as proper JSON.

Comment: Your json needs to be look like this:  https://3v4l.org/HVCA6

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. but i have one doubt.. if we give name Juliet"es and convert to json encode.. that will take 
{"Name": "Juliet"es"} 

. how to decode this object .? What will i do for this scenario..?

Comment: If your data contained `Juliet"es` and you _properly_ encoded this as JSON, then you would not be getting `{"Name": "Juliet"es"}` as a result in the first place. Your question how to decode _broken_ JSON makes rather little sense; see to it, that you _don’t_ break it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$convertedJson = json_decode(addslashes($jsonobj));`.
But has suggested by @Barmar and @CBroe , always generated JSON strings from array or object with json_encode().

Comment: Thank you for your answer... But I tried this, this is not working.. Because if multiple array is there that quote array was omitted by json_decode.